# Locally constant constructible vs locally constant

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

A very short and easy question. Why do people write "locally constant constructible sheaf" (e.g. everywhere in SGA) instead of just "locally constant sheaf"? A constructible sheaf is by definition locally constant on a stratification, hence locally constant implies locally constant constructible. And locally constant constructible implies locally constant. So the two notions should be the same. Have I misread the definitions?

Comment: Apparently "constructible" has a second meaning: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/69422/loaclly-constant-constructible-sheaves-and-finite-etale-coverings

Comment: Indeed, if we impose finiteness in the definition of constructibility, then "locally constant constructible sheaf" is a bit shorter than "locally constant sheaf of finite groups". On the other hand, the Stacks Project seems to be using "finite locally constant", which sounds nicer.

Comment: If I recall it correctly constructible does  require locally constant (with respect to a stratification) of finite rank (local system on each stratum)!

Answer (score 1):

Locally constant means locally constant on the whole space, not on a stratification, so constructible doesn't imply locally constant (or locally constant constructible). Depending on which SGA you are talking about, constructible imposes some finiteness conditions, so locally constant doesn't imply constructible.

Comment: But locally constant constructible *does* imply locally constant!